# A finite dimensional vector space that is not naturally isomorphic to its dual.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I need an example of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ that is not naturally isomorphic to $V^\ast$.

I know that, at least in finite dimensional case, there is a one-to-one correspondence between natural isomorphisms of $V$ to $V^*$ and nondegenerate bilinear forms on $V$; so for the above example it is enough to show a vector space without nondegenerate bilinear forms.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Clearly $V$ and $V^\ast$ are always isomorphic, but I need an isomorphism independent from a choice of a basis.

Comment: The question does not make sense. A _natural_ isomorphism is necessarily between functors, not objects. And of course every finite dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its dual. The point is that there is no natural isomorphism between $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{Vect}}$ and $(-)^*$... but how could there be? One is a covariant functor and the other is contravariant.

Comment: By the term "natural isomorphism" I mean "isomorphism independent from the choice of a basis".

Comment: But what does _that_ mean? That's just an informal phrase. For instance, if I assume the global axiom of choice, then every vector space has a canonical basis, and so I can canonically define a non-degenerate bilinear form on every finite-dimensional vector space, etc.

Comment: @ZhenLin Aren't you just working with the wrong categories and functors? If you define category $C$ to have object $V$ with automorphisms of $V$ as arrows, and category $D$ the same for $V^\ast$, and instead you use F(-)=$(-^{op})^\ast:C\to D$, it looks like for a nondegenerate form you have natural transformations of $Id_C\simeq F$ given  $\eta_x:V\to V^\ast$ defined by $\eta_x(v)=\langle v,x\rangle$. I just whipped it up, but it would be instructive if wrong. It really seems like it has a valid statement in category theory, but it doesn't have to be the same as the one for the double dual.

Comment: I might have modified the functor $F$ beyond just $(-^{op})^\ast$. In my doodling I asked for each arrow $f$ of $C$, $f^\ast(\phi)v:=\phi(f(v))$ to get an arrow from $V^\ast\to V^\ast$. It just seems like the right diagram only has automorphisms of $V$ to itself and $V^\ast$ to itself (changes of basis), just for a particular $V$. This doesn't have to be on the entire category of vector spaces over a field. If anybody spots a problem, please let me know: I lack confidence in stuff I came up with in under 10 minutes.

Comment: Changing the category is cheating. I could just look at the category where the only morphisms are identity morphisms – then naturality is trivial!

Answer (score 2):

People may well disagree with this, but let me essay an answer. Consider a line $L$ in the Euclidean plane. It makes sense to say whether a function $f\colon L\to\mathbb R$ is a polynomial function, because once you choose a coordinatization of $L$, such a function will be a polynomial in the single coordinate on $L$. Equally, it makes sense to speak of the polynomial functions of degree $<n$ on $L$, and we know that this is an $n$-dimensional real vector space. Since our space doesn’t have a natural basis, it’s not clear to me that there is any natural isomorphism with its dual space.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: give up your search: $\dim(V)=\dim(V^{\ast})$.

Comment: Of course they must be isomorphic, but in principal they still might not be "naturally" isomorphic, according to the author's request.

Comment: The Author is referring to this 1-1 correspondence: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Bilinear_products_and_dual_spaces

Comment: @rschwieb Well I see, but I doubt that there's a "natural correspondence" since all attributes of a finite  dimensional vector space recur on the fact that these vector spaces  are finite, i.e., they have a finite basis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but a finite dimensional vector space *always* has nondegenerate bilinear forms, hasn't it?

I mean: chose a basis of your vector space and you have an isomorphism $V \cong \mathbf{k}^n$, right?

Then, consider the bilinear form on $\mathbf{k}^n$ with associated matrix the identity -or whatever symmetric matrix $A$ you prefer with non-zero determinant:

$$
\varphi(X,Y) = X^tAY \ .
$$

And you have defined a nondegenerate bilinear form on $V$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: But is the resulting map between $V$ and its dual independent of your choices?

Comment: I'm not saying this. I'm just answering the question: "I need a finite dimensional vector space *without* a nondegenerate bilinear form." Ok, IMHO there is no such a thing.

Comment: You may very well be right, but that’s not what I understood the thrust of OP’s question to be.

Comment: "so for the above example it is enough to show a vector space without nondegenerate bilinear forms."

Comment: I yield! Once again, I read only part way through…